# Can you make 2 squares and 4 rightangled triangles using only 8 straight lines?

Tags: logical-deduction, geometry

Can you make exactly 2 squares and exactly 4 right-angled triangles using "only 8" that is exactly 8 straight lines?

I am looking for 3 different answers.

Comment: Exactly 2 squares and 4 right triangles, using exactly 8 lines? And are the shapes allowed to be overlapping?

Comment: I voted to close this because there are a lot of specifications that you left out of the puzzle, as shown by tfitzger's comment above. It's unclear whether the shapes can overlap, whether we need exactly 8 lines, if a larger shape can have a smaller shape inside, etc. This is also probably why people are downvoting it.

Comment: @MisterEman22 I'd say not so much "unclear what you're asking" as "too broad" - there must be many different ways of doing this. I haven't VTCed yet though.

Comment: @randal'thor That's what I was thinking until I saw the other votes. I reasoned that since it isn't fully explained, we can't really label it as too broad. If after being explained, there are still many ways to solve the puzzle, then it should be closed/stay closed by the reason of "too broad"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This figure can be drawn using 8 straight lines. You can easily see 4 triangles and square, and the border of the figure forms a larger square.

[image]

Comment: darn you beat me by 17 seconds. I just got it drawn up in paint

Comment: @mike damm man,,, that was fast..

Comment: Plus any pair of squares inscribed like this works - no need to have everything be isosceles!

Comment: What program did you use to make the image?

Comment: @user1717828 Latex, with the tikz package

Answer (score 2):

I can do it using only 7, as follows:

[image]

Comment: very nice , but here we need 8 lines ..

Comment: @jatin2302 You say "only 8"; does that mean exactly 8 then?

Comment: but 8 means 8 only.. not 7 or not 9 :)

Comment: @jatin2302 OK, sorted! It's exactly 8 now, but not so neat :-)

Comment: 2 square and 4 right angle triangle brother

Comment: @jatin2302 Dammit! Edited out.

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm